# Adding new custom field to  existing content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-field-api

I' m using a module in creating certain pages, but i want to add an extra field to each page where the admin can modify

I ' m kinda lost , not sure how to do it

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to use a content type -

First Create the content type in the Drupal menu then add your field to the content type

Hope this helps ...